# What is a concise way of counting how many requests were sent?

Tags: javascript, typescript, http, request, counter

I am wondering how to count the number of sent requests concisely. There is an API that allows you to send maximum 50 requests in a minute to any endpoint of that API. Every 60 seconds they reset the number of requests that I sent to zero again, after the first request were sent.
I need to do a lot of requests and I wonder, how I can keep track of them correctly.

```
async dataCollector(){
    let urlList = this.urlList; // 100+ urls
    for(let url in urlList){
      await this.getResource(url).then( data =>
        // do something with data
      )
}
```

Now I have to somehow check in `getResource()` how many requests I sent and so on such that I just wait until more requests are available. What would be the best way to check them?

```
getResource(url){
    return this.http.get(url);
}
```

I appreciate any advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep a count of the requests sent, and the time of the first request. You also need a way to wait for the previous requests, that can be done with a Promise chain:

```
 chain = Promise.resolve();
 count = 0;
 first = undefined;

 aquireSlot() {
    return this.chain = this.chain.then(async () => {
       if(this.count >= 20) {
         await timer(60_000 - (Date.now() - this.first));
         this.count = 0;
         this.first = undefined;
       }
       if(!this.first) this.first = Date.now();
       this.count += 1;
    });
 }

 async getResource(url){
   await this.aquireSlot();
   return await this.http.get(url);
 }

  // the implementation of timer is left to the reader
```

With this code, every `getResource` call kind of ends in a queue (a promise chain). If the queue only has less than 20 elements, the chain simply continues and the calls are done. If there are 20 elements, the queue is paused till at least 60 seconds passed since the first call. Then the count is reset, and the whole thing repeats.

Comment: Hello Jonas, thank you for your answer! I will try it and  notify you about how it works!

Comment: There's a scenario where this will fail: If in the first minute 10 calls are done, then 30 in the second minute, it'll pause at the 20th call, but as one minute passed already it'll simply continue. I guess that situation can be handled with something like `if(Date.now() - this.first > 60_000) { this.count = 0; this.first = Date.now(); }` ... but as I'm quite busy at the moment I won't try

Comment: Hey, I have an additional question: How could I use this concept with ```map```. I filter the urls where no data exits like that: ```await Promise.all(
                releases.map(release => this.service.getResource(release.resource_url).catch(() => {null}))
            ).then(responses => {
                const successfulResponses = responses.filter(response => response != null); ... ``` It is mapping without checking whether you can or not